# Intra Company Transfer to Germany : Choices to leave the company

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

I got intra company transfered (from India) to Germany 1.5 year back with a contract term of 2 years (Blue Card)

I wish to continue working long term in Germany and Would like to understand, if anyone has experienced, the choices to stay back and switch the current employer IF the current contract doesn't get extended.

My current Blue Card holds the name of the current employer, and states that I need to work for the same for at least 24 months.

My Queries :

(Current Employer Contract - Valid)

1. Can I switch from my current employer, provided IF I get another offer from a different company. How this current Visa/Blue card would be transfered and its validity extended ? How many months before should I apply for VISA/Blue card to be transfered to the new company ?

(Current Employer Contract - Expired)

2. If the current contract gets expired and doesn't get extended, can I continue staying here in Germany and look for another job. I have heard that a Fiktionsbescheinigung can be obtained and not much information I could find online. Is it valid in all cases ? Do some condition apply ?

(Current Employer Contract - Extended)

3. If the current contract does get extended, how many months before should I remind my company to provided the hard copy to get the Blue card updated ?

I understand that question may be confusing, please feel free to query me back. I did try to find answers online, but there exists no specific information as it all depends on Auslaenderbehoerde or Rathaus. I only intend to understand the possibility and a standard process (if any)

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

In cases 1 and 3: once a new contract has been concluded

- you must inform the **Ausländerbehörde** of the change

that will lead to the extension of the Blue Card, when the work type and salary fullfils the conditions of the Blue Card.

In case 2: residence can continue during the time you receive unemployment benefits earn during your previous work.
If you can support yourself, a further 6 months as a Job-search visa can be issued.

- again through the **Ausländerbehörde**

---

A **permanent** (*Niederlassungserlaubnis*) can be applied for after 33 months

- if you have a B1 German Language qualification

  - after 21 months

---

All of this is **Visa D** sub type **Blue Card EU** specific

- other **Visa D** sub types have very different conditions

Comment: Providing a source for your answer would be helpful.

Comment: @Traveller the source will be a combination the local Ausländerbehörde and Blue Card regulations. The OP asked for a overview so that she knows what **keywords** to when searching or asking for.